# children's Tylenol on Pesach

Tags: medicine, passover, chametz-leaven

This year, Rabbi Bess's list of non-*chametz* products doesn't AFAICT include any kosher-for-*Pesach* children's analgesic/fever reducer (acetaminophen/paracetamol) (except one that includes also antihistamine). What to do if, *chalila*, a kid needs some on *Pesach*? Any ideas (besides suppositories and calling my rabbi)?

Comment: It does not say children's ibuprofen either?

Answer (score 4):

Adwe makes a Kosher for Passover children's Acetaminophen. It is available online at http://www.koshervitamins.com/shop/stores_app/Browse_dept_items.asp?showpage=1&Search_Text=1&AZ=Pain+Relief+(Children)&Brand=Adwe+Laboratories

Comment: Thank you. That is good to know. But even better would be advice one can use on _Pesach_ if he didn't buy the Adwe stuff beforehand (and it's unavailable in local stores). (OTOH, maybe one should just buy that stuff by mail-order in case he needs it: it's not terribly expensive, as children's APAP goes.)

Comment: Hm, actually, that Web site is not accepting orders until after _Pesach_.

Comment: Send me via e-mail what you need and your address and I will pick it up locally and send it to you on Monday

Comment: Thank you! But I think your hassle (and my shipping costs) are not worth the _chashash_ that I might, _chalila_, need the medicine: there are always suppositories if I do. I was hoping more for an answer that said "here's what you can do with adult medicine for kids" or "here's a national brand that Rabbi Ploni says is kosher for _Pesach_ although it isn't on Rabbi Bess's list". But, really, thank you for the offer; perhaps another 'out-of-towner' will take you up on it, if you're willing....

Answer (score 4):

In a pinch, you could crush a 225 mg tylenol tablet and dissolve it in an amount of water that will yield 160mg/5mL, which is the ratio in Children's Tylenol. Of course, CYLMP (call your local medical professional) first!

Answer (score 1):

Tylenol is listed as okay on the cRc list from a few years ago: listed as recommended are:

"Tylenol (All) (Children’s Tablets & Liquid, Children’s Cold Chew Tabs, Infant’s Cold & Fever Reducer), Tylenol (Allergy Sinus, Allergy Cold Medicine No Drow, Flu Nttm hot Medication, Max Strength Flu NightTime, Max Strgth Flu Nttme Liquid, Max Strgth Sinus Nittm, Max Strgth Allergy Sinus Nttme, PM Xtra Strgth, Severe Allergy Caplets, Sinus Medication Maximum Strgth, Multi Symptom Cold Medication)"

http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/crc2004medications/

That was before the cRc changed their policy to allow all pill medications and not list medicines individually (in what many kashrus professionals I spoke to considered a sharp rebuke to R. Bess) because of the potential danger that by issuing such lists, some people might not take medicine they otherwise should.

So the only question would be whether the formulation changed substantially since 2004?

Comment: There was the recall of Tylenol and several other children's medicines last year, since which (as far as I know) they're made in a different plant. So the formulation may indeed have changed, or perhaps the alcohol or whatever that they use is derived from grain rather than other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Triaminic recently started making a l[iquid acetaminophen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003V9MCQW). It's recommended in this year's cRc Guide.

Comment: The cRc's guide lists "Triaminic Multi-Symptom Fever Reducer (Bubble Gum Flavor)", which is not the product this answer links to, and which is not just acetaminophen/paracetamol.